# List comprehension being passed to Ordered Dict creation is being created as a reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I am trying to create a ordered dic for a given set of keys. 
I structure i am going for is `

```
     OrderedDict([('A', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 
                  ('B', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 
                  ('C', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 
                  ('D', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])])`
```

This is being created by the following function.

> d = OrderedDict.fromkeys(keys, [0 for _ in range(10)])

I am successfully getting the required structure.

The problem is the values of the dict all are being created as references. Meaning when i try to do the following `d['A'][1] = "11111"`
it changed values of every key given.
i get the result as the following.

```
    OrderedDict([('A', [0, '11111', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 
                 ('B', [0, '11111', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 
                 ('C', [0, '11111', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 
                 ('D', [0, '11111', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])])
```

i did try deepcopy but didnt really help. 
the work around i currently have is

```
d['A'] = d['A'][:]
```

i dont really like the above soln because i have about `6mil keys and values`.. so doing this is a bit of a hassle.

I would like to know a better way of doing this.. and also why this is happening.

Comment: I believe if you can iterate over each list and call `list()` on it, you'll get a list which is not made up of linked references.

Comment: @JammyDodger i did try this didnt seem to work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classmethod [`fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) uses the *same* default value for all dictionary keys.

To avoid that, specify a new instance for each key:

```
d = OrderedDict((k, [0]*10) for k in keys)
```